# How to make the flutter app shows as it's an IOS version app inside android

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app on an android device, it shows the app with the android adaptive things such as the date picker, the app bar, the dialogs...

I want to try a version of the app like it's on IOS, I mean I want that date picker shows as the IOS's, also for the app bar.

I'm pretty sure that this is related to the `MediaQuery`, but I just don't know what is it.

I know that I can show forcefully the widgets from the `Cupertino` library, however, I don't want to do it, I want just to get how the app will show when it runs on IOS with the current code.

Thank you !

Comment: you need to run the code on an ios simulator or a real ios device or you can run on an macos device as native mac app.

Comment: I know, I am asking is there anything that would get me to see how it will look on IOS in android

Comment: i guess that''s not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: actually, I got the idea of this from the https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview package, which gives a preview of the app on different device with many other features,  and I couldn't get how it's done from it's code

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you're setting your theme, you can simply set the [`platform` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/platform.html) on it to `TargetPlatform.iOS`.

This should allow the theming to use iOS-specific widgets rather than their android counterparts. Note that this may not work everywhere; if [Dart:io's Platform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html) were used incorrectly in your code or 3rd party code for theming, this would not be overridden.